# Jquery Image Hover stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make jQuery hover images but the code doesn't work properly, it show me nothing.
I paste my code to explain and I hope someone can help me with this...

**gallery.html**

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/default.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="gallery">
 <ul class="items">
  <ul>
     <li><span class="img_frame"><a href="img/s6300159.jpg"><img src="img/test1.jpg" /></a></span><div class="img_desc"><span>22</span></div></li>
     <li><span class="img_frame"><a href="img/s6300159.jpg"><img src="img/test1.jpg" /></a></span><div class="img_desc"><span>23</span></div></li>
     <li><span class="img_frame"><a href="img/s6300159.jpg"><img src="img/test1.jpg" /></a></span><div class="img_desc"><span>24</span></div></li>
  </ul>
 </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.gallery {overflow:hidden; width:1000px;}
.gallery .items { margin-bottom:50px; height:320px; }
.gallery .items li { position:relative; float:left;  width:290px; height:180px; margin-right:38px; margin-bottom: 30px; }
 .gallery .items li img { width:277px; height:165px; }

 .img_desc {
position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 10px; 
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #ffffff;
color: #262626;  
background: url(img/benefits_on.png) repeat;
width: 36px;
right: 5px;
text-align: center;
    }


    .img_frame {
    margin-top:3px;
     padding:1px;
     display:inline-block;
     line-height:0px;
     background:#fff;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
      }

    .img_frame img {
     padding:1px;
     border:4px solid #f2f1f0;
    }
    .img_frame a { display:block; }

    .hover_image { background:url("img/preview_image.png") center center no-repeat; }
```

**default.js**

```
<!-- Image hover effect -->
function image_hover(frame){
var link_content = jQuery(frame).find('a[href^=http], a[href*=www], a[href=#], a[href$=html], a[href$=php], a[href$=asp], a[href$=htm], a[href$=shtml], a[href$=aspx]');
var image_content = jQuery(frame).find('a[href$=jpg], a[href$=png], a[href$=gif], a[href$=jpeg]');
var video_content = jQuery(frame).find('a[href*=vimeo], a[href*=youtube], a[href*=swf], a[href*=flv], a[href*=avi], a[href*=mov], a[href*=mpg]');

link_content.addClass("hover_link");
image_content.removeClass("hover_link").addClass("hover_image");
video_content.removeClass("hover_link").addClass("hover_video");

jQuery(frame).find("a > img").hover(
    function() {
        if(!jQuery(this).parent().hasClass("no_hover")){
            jQuery(this).stop().animate({"opacity": ".6"}, "400");
        }
    },
    function() {
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "400");
});

jQuery(frame).children("a.no_hover").removeClass("hover_image");
return false;
}

jQuery(function(){

image_hover('.img_frame');
 });
```

........................

Comment: Can you narrow the problem down and edit the post to show smaller amounts of code?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of hover effect you want to achieve? In my case its showing me some glowing border or something like this as its lowering its opacity and the background is pulling up. If this is what you want you might have done mistake int your `.hover_image` class's image location. Try giving a background color of that class like

```
.hover_image { background:#ff0000 url("img/preview_image.png") center center no-repeat; }
```

you may get the effect exactly what i was getting.

Comment: My mistake inside default.js ( SOLVED )

Comment: would you mind explaining exactly what you were looking for and how did you solved it?